# Why does this filter work on a List<T> but not on an IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I need to create an extension method that will filter collection `List<TSource>` according to a list of validation rules `List<<IRule>, bool>`.
But I get an error `VisitSubQueryExpression method is not implemented` and I don't see/can not find what is the problem cause.

**This is my extension method:**

```
public static List<TSource> ValidItems<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
                                  List<IValidationRule<TSource>> validationRules)
{
     return source.Where(testableItem => 
            validationRules.All(rule => rule.RulePassed(testableItem))).ToList();
}
```

**IRule interface:**

```
public interface IValidationRule<T> //with implementation class ValidationRule<T>
{
    Func<T, bool> RulePassed { get; set; }
    //... +other code
}
```

**Sample of extension method call**

```
//initialization of List<SampleType> listToValidate = ... 
var validItems = listToValidate.ValidItems(
                  new List<IValidationRule<SampleType>() {
                       new ValidationType<SampleType> {
                       RulePassed = (s) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SampleType.Name), 
                       //...initalize other ValidationType parameters
                       }
                   });
```

this sample should filter listToValidate list and remove all SampleType instances, with Name property that is Null or Whitespace

What is wrong with my extension method? What does this "VisitSubQueryExpression method is not implemented" error mean?

**if I change it to be an extension method for `List<TSource>` not `IQueryable<TSource>` - it works! Why?**

replacing `this IQueryable<TSource>` with `this List<TSource>`, it works, why? `Where` method should work on `IQueryable<T>` (inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`), shouldn't it?

```
public static List<TSource> ValidItems<TSource>(this List<TSource> source, 
                                  List<IValidationRule<TSource>> validationRules)
{
     return source.Where(testableItem => 
            validationRules.All(rule => rule.RulePassed(testableItem))).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Do you use this directly in a linq-2-entities query?

Comment: Why are you using `IQueryable<T>` over `IEnumerable<T>`? The former is useful if you want to translate the filter expression into something the database understands (e.g. SQL). Unless your query provider has special support for `IValidationRule` (pretty unlikely) it won't be able to handle that expression.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I was planning to use it on LinqToExcel returned 'ExcelQueryable<T>' which inherits from 'QueryableBase<T>', so I thought I could do my filtering before turning resulting collection to List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rule.RulePassed` cannot be translated by your IQueryable provider.

```
public static List<TSource> ValidItems<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
                              List<IValidationRule<TSource>> validationRules)
{
    var result = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (var testableItem in source)
    {
        if (validationRules.All(rule => rule.RulePassed(testableItem))
        {
            result.Add(testableItem);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The sample you provided is another "workaround" that works, I was just wondering why it doesn't work directly on IQueryable<T> - So this error message "VisitSubQueryExpression method is not implemented" is from IQueryable provider?

Comment: @Prokurors it's not "from", your provider just doesn't support it.

Comment: ok, so in this case I need to load all the list in-memory (using IEnumerable instead of IQueryable) and only then filter it using my validation rules...  it's a bit strange because (IQueryable).Where works with Func<TSource, bool> expression, so why doesn't it work with an extension method which has Func<TSource, bool> argument? Ok, in my case it's List<Func<TSource, bool>>... but otherwise it seems to be the same...

Comment: How do you expect it to work on your db side? It probably doesn't have a `rule.RulePassed` implemented...

Comment: hmm... if I create a `Func<T, bool> predicate = (p)=>p.Name.StartsWith("P");` I can use it in `IQueryable<T>.Where(predicate);` And **it works**. My idea was to have something like list of predicates - "validation rules". This RulePassed is just a `Func<T, bool>` so I guess the problem is with having "a list"... and it can not work with `IEnumerable.All()` method, not the problem with RulePassed.  So I think it would work if I would transform my list of `Func<T, bool>` to chain of `Where` calls in my extension method... Thank you for your help, your answers was most helpful!

Comment: @Prokurors if you use a delegete type the IEnumerable overload will be chosen. For IQueryable you'd need to use an Expression type.

Answer (score 1):

`IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` but not vice versa. And `List<T>` doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>`.

This is the list of interfaces exposed by List:
[image]

Since both `IQueryable` and `IList` inherit from `IEnumerable<T>` you could use that and call [`.AsQueryable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20379242/736079) on it to convert both cases.

Comment: Hmm... maybe you thought that extension method should be for IEnumerable and then use it (ilist).AsEnumerable().(extension method) and (iqueryable).AsEnumerable().(extension method)?

Comment: IQueryable already implements IEnumerable and IList does as well. So you would not need to cast it or call AsEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` does not implement `IQueryable<T>`, so you can't call an extension method on it defined on `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Actually I was trying to call extension method on ExcelQueryable (which inherits from QueryableBase<T> which inherits from IQueryable<T>), List<T> is just the return type