# Assign DbSet and query result to same variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using the following code to allow for users to search for other registered users in order to add them to a friends list:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RegisteredUsers")]
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    //list of registered users
    var regUsers = db.Users;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        regUsers = regUsers.Where(s => s.User.LastName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(regUsers.ToList());
}
```

Yet I am getting an error on line 9 at `regUsers = regUsers.Where(..)`, stating:

> "cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<ETLToolKit.Models.User>` to `System.Data.entity.DbSet<ETLToolKit.Models.User>`

How can I reuse the `regUsers` variable?

Comment: Why don't you use an other variable to store the results? `db.Users` is an other type than the result set in your `Where` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear.

You have two different types in your code:

- `db.Users`: a `DbSet<User>`
- `regUsers.Where(s => s.User.LastName.Contains(searchString))`: an `IQueryable<User>`

By using this statement:

```
var regUsers = db.Users;
```

You're declaring `regUsers` to be of the type of the right-hand side of the assignment: `DbSet<User>`.

You cannot assign the result of `Where()` to that same variable, because the result of `Where()` is not a `DbSet<User>`.

Declare the variable explicitly to be of a common ancestral type (`IQueryable<User>`, which both types implement):

```
IQueryable<Users> users = db.Users;
```

Now you can assign the result of `Where()` to the same variable:

```
users = users.Where(s => s.User.LastName.Contains(searchString));
```

So the code will look like this:

```
IQueryable<User> users = db.Users;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    users = users.Where(s => s.User.LastName.Contains(searchString));
}

return View(users.ToList());
```

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
IQueryable<User> regUsers = db.Users;
```

db.Users is of Type DbSet, so when you do your `Where` call, it tries to implicitly assign a value of different type to `regUsers`, which doesn't work - hence the error.

EDIT: As others have pointed out, the call to `AsQueryable` can be omitted. regUsers is now explicitly of type IQueryable.

Comment: So, first convert to `IQueryable` and than to `List`? I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: There is no need to call `AsQueryable()`, `DbSet<T>` already implements `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

Write as below:

```
regUsers = regUsers.Where(s => s.User.LastName.Contains(searchString)).AsQueryable();
```

This will convert into your desired result!

For more details:

[What is the purpose of AsQueryable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366907/what-is-the-purpose-of-asqueryable)

**EDIT:**

As per the comment better approach would be as below:

```
IQueryable<User> users = db.Users;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    users = users.Where(s => s.User.LastName.Contains(searchString));
}

return View(users.ToList());
```

Comment: So, first convert to `IQueryable` and than to `List`? I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, omit the reuse of the variable which is of conflicting types and pass the list directly into the `View`:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RegisteredUsers")]
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{   
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        return View(db.Users.Where(s => s.User.LastName.Contains(searchString)).ToList);
    }

    return View(new List<User>());
    //or if you want to return all users:
    return View(db.Users.ToList()); //you might want to consider `Skip` and `Take`
}
```

With special thanks to @CodeCaster:
If your query becomes more complex:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RegisteredUsers")]
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{   
    IQueryable<User> query = db.Users;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.User.LastName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    //additional filtering can be applied to `query`

    return View(query.ToList());    
}
```

Comment: This won't return the list of users if searchString is null or empty.

Comment: And now you have `db.Users` in code twice, which can be prevented by using a variable of the proper type.

Comment: @CodeCaster: it only hits the execution path once. I am trying to point out that the use of a variable is not really needed. I wouldn't store the `db.Users` in a separate variable here since, I think the intentions are clear. If the query becomes more complex, then yes I would prefer a variable indeed. I'll update it.

Comment: You're right about that, but I think it keeps the code more readable and maintainable. Anyway using `var query = db.Users;` we're back to square one.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Oops, my bad.