# AsEnumerable and AsQueryable which one should be used in Client - WCF Service

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a Service it returns the data of type `List<Boss>`.

> **This Question is Purely depends on Service Call, not a DB Context**

The Model Classes are

```
public class Boss
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public List<PayrollInfo> PayInfo { get; set; }
}

public class PayrollInfo
{
    public int Monthof2015 { get; set; }
    public int NetWorkingDays { get; set; }
    public int AbsentDays { get; set; }
}
```

Just Imagine the Service

```
[OperationContract]
List<Boss> GetDataMale();
```

Outline of the Method should be

```
public List<Boss> GetDataMale()
{
    using(var db = new DBContext)
    {
        return db.Boss.Where(x => x.Gender == "Male").ToList();
    }
}
```

Now Consider the Client Side:

```
using(var client = new ServiceProvider())
{
    var bListEnum = client.GetDataMale().AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.Role == "Manager");
    var bListQuery = client.GetDataMale().AsQueryable().Where(m => m.Role == "Manager");
}
```

Let I know which one is preferable in Client ? Kindly explain the operational differentiation of these two statements.

> ```
>     var bListEnum = client.GetDataMale().AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.Role == "Manager");
>     var bListQuery = client.GetDataMale().AsQueryable().Where(m => m.Role == "Manager");
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Your server returns a list. On the client side this will be translated to either a `List<>` or an array. But *both* already implement `IEnumerable<>` so the answer is: **neither**. Just drop it.

```
var managers = client.GetDataMale().Where(m => m.Role == "Manager");
```

You can find a very nice explanation of what `AsQueryable()` does right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366907/what-is-the-purpose-of-asqueryable). Basically, as you *know* you have an in-memory collection and your operation does not need an `IQueryable<>`, calling `AsQueryable()` does nothing for you here.

Comment: If I used AsQueryable() in between the result and where condition. What it means ? If it is a db means it will create a SQL syntax. But here what it does? Can you please explain me please...