# In entity framework 6 SelectMany to Join option for query throwing error The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable<MyModel>

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I have a following query throwing error as mentioned in subject

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>> GetDataAsync()
{
    return await _context.baseTable.SelectData().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
    
public static IQueryable<MyModel> SelectData(this IQueryable<relet> baseTable)
{
    return baseTable
        .Where(h => h.table1 != null && h.table1.table2 != null)
        .Select(lev => new {
            table3Collection = lev.table1.table2.table3, //table3 is ICollection
            Table5Key = lev.table5 != null ? lev.table5.id : null,
            Table4Key = lev.table1.table2.table4 != null ?  lev.table1.table2.table4.id : null,
        }).ToList()
        .SelectMany(x => {
            return x.table3Collection.Select(h => new MyModel() {
                ContactKey = new Key
                {
                    Id = h.Id,
                    Type = h.Type
                },
                Table5Key = x.Table5Key,
                Table4Key = x.Table4Key
    
            });
        })
        .AsQueryable();
}
```

Can someone Give me idea how to use same LINQ query in group join way? Problem is occuring at .ToListAsync() line

Comment: You don't have `ToListAsync()` anywhere in the code you have shown us!

Comment: It is called in the calling method

Comment: You should show us ___all___ the relevant code. The easy answer is don't return IQueryable and don't call `AsQueryable()` then!

Comment: That thing is already achieved. Any way I can Convert my List to AsyncList . basically i wanted to await the result

Comment: Show us some more code (edit the question) that includes where the error is actually thrown and explain in detail what you're trying to acheive (again edit the question to add this detail).

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743165/toarrayasync-throws-the-source-iqueryable-doesnt-implement-iasyncenumerable

Comment: What happens if you remove `.AsQueryable()`

Comment: I think Queryable support async. if i remove it i will lost it

Comment: What type does `SelectMany` return? Does that type also implement `IQueryable`?

Comment: SelectMany always return IEnumerable and here it is returning MyModel enumrable which i am converting to Asqueryable

Comment: Only Problem I agains saying is with ToListAsync()

Comment: Why did you use `ToList()` in `SelectData()`? At this point you loaded everything in memory *synchronously*. The rest of the code is an in-memory query so `ToListAsync()` would make no sense even if it was possible. Using `AsQueryable()` won't change the fact you already loaded the results in memory

Comment: What are you trying to do with that query? EF Core (and all ORMs) deal with *Entities and classes*, not tables. You aren't writing an embedded SQL query, you're writing an ORM query that will be mapped to SQL. Complicated queries like this are almost always a smell and an attempt to rewrite SQL as LINQ

Comment: If you want to execute anything asynchronously, split this long chain of calls at `ToList()` and replace it with `ToListAsync()`. After that, process the results with the rest of the code, as IEnumerables

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create `IQueryable` from `IEnumerable` and use asynchronous extensions. Actually you just need to correct your query and remove unnecessary materializations.

```cs
public static IQueryable<MyModel> SelectData(this IQueryable<relet> baseTable)
{
    return 
        from lev in baseTable
        from t3 in lev.table1.table2.table3
        select new MyModel
        {
            ContactKey = new Key
            {
                Id = lev.Id,
                Type = lev.Type
            },
            Table5Key = (int?)lev.table5.Id,
            Table4Key = (int?)lev.table1.table2.table4.Id
        };
}
```

Note that from simplified query we can see that `t3` is not used. It means that we just duplicate records.

Comment: work for Linq to sql. Looking For thing where Linq To Object will work

Comment: I will not work for `IEnumerable`, and it has no sense. Linq to Objects do not use IO operations and there is no needed to supply async extensions in such case.